# How to Convert PhpStorm theme into a Sublime Theme?

Tags: phpstorm, sublimetext3

I have a heavily customized theme in PhpStorm that I've fine tuned over the years to my exact liking, which is based off of the ["Heat of the Night" theme](http://www.phpstorm-themes.com/theme/heat-night).

I currently jump around various themes for Sublime such as Soda Dark, Monokai Dark, etc.

Besides doing it manually, is there a tool or any other way to convert my PhpStorm theme to a Sublime theme?